# How to perform ExpandableListView child click

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I create an Expandable ListView which contains 3 group and each group have several child.

In OnCreate i expand group one with exLv.expandGroup(0); then i want to click child of this group without user touch it (dynamically).
I tried exLv.setSelectedChild and it didn't work.
I just want to do this one time at the onCreate. How to do this?

Comment: you want to perform specific child click? before expanding the list? i dont know how you want to do that, since you cant see any children at that point. please explain your problem a little better

Comment: no first i expand one group and then want to perform child click dynamic.

Comment: so, tried the OnChildClickListener in the answer section?
Whats your problem using that callback?

You want every child to have a custom click event?
then you need to add the listeners in getView.

Comment: look i create expandable listview and in onCreate method expand one group dynamic(e.g listItems.expandGroup(0);). then want to click for example first child of group one dynamically.

Comment: i think dynamically doesnt mean what you think it means. you want to select the first  child by default when expanding a group? thats whats called automatically. Then implement an OnGroupClickListener and hand click event off to first child as well

Comment: please see the post again, i edited it.

Comment: please google the meaning of dynamically to make thats what you really mean. To it makes no sense, and ive already told you what to do, in order to click the first child of the group. until you provide code of an attempt to do what i suggested i wont do any coding for you ;)

Answer (score -2):

In your activity class override the OnChildClickListener() method from list view.

```
expandbleList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

           //do something here.

        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry but did you notice what i want to do? i want perform child click dynamically.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? do you want to perform click automatically without user touch list item?

Comment: try this setSelectedChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean shouldExpandGroup)

Comment: yes exactly i want to click without user touch. i tried setSelectedChild but it didn't work.